# Ruby: loop with index?

Tags: ruby, loops

Sometimes, I use Ruby's [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) instead of [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each) when I want to keep track of the index. Is there a method like `Kernel#loop_with_index` I could use instead of [`Kernel#loop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop)?

Answer (score 23):

loop without a block results in an Enumerator, which has a `with_index`  method (and a `each_with_index` if you prefer that.)

```
loop.with_index{|_, i| puts i; break if i>100}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Fixnum#upto](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Integer.html#method-i-upto) with [Float::INFINITY](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Float.html#INFINITY).

```
0.upto(Float::INFINITY) do |i|
  puts "index: #{i}"
end
```

But, I'd probably just use `Kernel#loop` and keep track of the index myself because that seems simpler.

```
i = 0
loop do
  puts "index: #{i}"
  i += 1
end
```

So, yeah, I don't think there's anything like `Kernel#loop_with_index`.

Answer (score 3):

In recent Ruby versions, [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) has a default limit of Infinity and a step-size of 1.

```
0.step{|i| puts i ; break if i>100 }
```